# Implementing a Master/Worker pattern with PUB/SUB using ZeroMQ

Tags: python, c++, zeromq

I have written a toy Master/Worker" or "task farm" using ZeroMQ.

[image: Master/Worker Pattern1]

This is what I have got so far - but I want to add `PUB/SUB`, so that the workers listen and respond to topics (either specific topics, or wildcard matches).

#### master

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import random
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process

import zmq
from zmq.devices.basedevice import ProcessDevice

REQ_ADDRESS = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:6240'
REP_ADDRESS = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:6241'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start queue
    context = zmq.Context()
    sock_in = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    sock_in.bind(REQ_ADDRESS)
    sock_out = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    sock_out.bind(REP_ADDRESS)
    zmq.device(zmq.QUEUE, sock_in, sock_out)
```

#### worker

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import random
import time

import zmq

REP_ADDRESS = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:6241'

def receive_tasks():
    """
    Client action: request tasks
    """
    # ID: just to show that we're getting the right replies
    my_id = random.randint(1, 1000000)
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.connect(REP_ADDRESS)
    while True:
        # Data is received here. Note that this blocks until
        # we get a job.
        job = socket.recv_json()
        # Do work here
        time.sleep(0.5)
        # Send the result back. Pass any JSON-serializable object.
        socket.send_json([my_id, job['id'], job['task_id']])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    receive_tasks()
```

#### client

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import random

import zmq
from zmq.core.poll import select

REQ_ADDRESS = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:6240'

def request_tasks():
    """
    Client action: request tasks
    """
    # ID: just to show that we're getting the right replies
    my_id = random.randint(1, 1000000)
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.connect(REQ_ADDRESS)
    for i in xrange(100):
        job = {'id': my_id, 'task_id': random.randint(1, 100)}
        socket.send_json(job)
        # Selects the sockets that have READ, WRITE, and ERROR
        # events respectively within the lists, with timeout 5.
        # Same API as: http://docs.python.org/library/select.html
        (rlist, wlist, xlist) = select([socket], [], [], 5)
        if len(rlist) > 0:
            # This receives the reply and deserializes it from JSON.
            msg = socket.recv_json()
            print('Client {0}, task #{1}: received work from {2} (for: {3})'.format(
                my_id, i+1, msg[0], msg[1]))
        else:
            print('Client {0}, task#{1}: error, timeout reached.'.format(my_id,
                i+1))
            socket.close()
            socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
            socket.connect(REQ_ADDRESS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    request_tasks()
```

My question is: how can I modify the master and workers to be "TOPIC aware" - using `PUB/SUB`?

Note: Although my example code is in Python, and the image illustration refers to Java - I'm actually writing my real code in C++, so please (if possible) don't use any language specifics in your answer.

Comment: Do you have any authenticated reference to this pattern? If so, please add it to the tag's guidance.

Comment: @GertArnold it is known as Master/Worker (formerly Master/Slave), I have created the tag `master-worker` since it did not exist previously

Comment: I know you created it, that's why I asked. Creating tags comes with a responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q :** *<sub>... how can I modify the master and workers to be "TOPIC aware" - using PUB/SUB?</sub>*

Welcome, the `PUB/SUB`-Scalable Formal Communication Pattern Archetype has one silent trap (caveat if not reading full details from ZeroMQ API) - the `SUB`-side has to actively subscribe to something, otherwise it receives nothing until doing so (as like with the real newspapers, one will never find any at the doorstep, unless a subscriptions was both raised & paid - here the costs are split between `PUB-SUB` `Context()`-engines, in early versions doing the TOPIC-filtering of (all) delivered messages ALAP, i.e. after delivery to (all) `SUB`-side (yes, network-I/O & many-times (distributed) CPU-loads were a way to "offload" the `PUB`-side costs for doing so in a hell-fast cadence & volumes. Later versions, post v3.4+ IIRC, 've moved the TOPIC-management + TOPIC-filtering onto the `PUB`-side (preventing network-I/O, yet demanding RAM+CPU resources of the `PUB`-side to be tuned-up adequately for large-scale deployments. Professional FinTech INDU was more than happy with performance & latency envelopes, so no need to panic prematurely on this))

ZeroMQ **`PUB`**-archetype TOPIC-filtering has been ever since based on the actual message payload Byte-stream, so given some **`SUB`**-s have already setup their active subscription to **`"ABC"`**, the `PUB`-side will make any message-payload, starting with **"`ABC`....."**, indeed placed into their respective delivery-queue(s). TOPIC-filter subscription management is well defined in the ZeroMQ documentation, just wanted to notice the default state, where no subscription is present at all and omitting to mention **`""`**-string subscription ( to receive everything ), which would produce rather absurd results in Master/Worker herd case, where any work-package would get processed by each and every Worker which (except for in some ultimate,yet gigantically expensive & inefficient fault-fighting robustness-increasing approach) would make no sense, having no other ( performance, latency or other ) benefit for doing so.

This said, there are no other limitations for designing a meta-plane network of any amount of additional Signalling & Communication "socket"-archetypes, that altogether fulfill the job:

---

Master
can

**`PUB.{ bind | setsockopt | send | close }()`** in due order & fashion, resulting in a cheap way <sub>(... latency + RAM + CPU related remarks above still valid ...)</sub> distribute job-tasks only to those, who have actively subscribed to do so ( a "herd"-management could handle newcomers, lost ones, N-replicated job-tasking, all just by using the TOPIC-filtering tricks )

Can use
**`PULL.{ bind | setsockopt | poll | receive | close }()`** accordingly, so as to efficiently, best in some "soft/mild"-real-time driven control-loop, collect results for the above distributed workpackages' results, validating them against (un)authorised and/or (non)tampered controlling checkups, as needed

Can also
"soft"-signal about (un)authenticated worker(s), for presence / health-status / state-of-work, if needed, be it by re-using the primary `PUB/SUB` channel and receiving answers via the primary `PUSH/PULL` one. Yet there is no problem to setup a knowingly separate, offloading, secondary signalling `PUB/SUB` channels among Master/Workers, so as to keep this "soft"-signalling flow independently of the primary workloads ( indeed growing a more professional SIG/COMMs meta-plane architecture for custom-defined [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) )

Soft-signalling channel is a typical way how to create some kind of domain-specific-language (having a grammar of "commands") for controlling the "herd" throughout the whole lifecycle of the such defined [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system).

Cool, isn't it?

---

Client ( doing a set of selective work-types )
can
**`SUB.{ connect | setsockopt | receive | close }()`** in due order & fashion, to so as to adaptively setup, configure & receive subscribed-to work-packages from `PUB`, yet keeping any other complexity of STATE-signalling & DATA-inter-communication with other, principally unrestricted set of peers )

Can use
**`PUSH.{ connect | setsockopt | send | close }()`** accordingly, so as to match the Master's way how to deliver (+ auth, ev. +protect against tampering ) any and all results for the above received workpackages' results, self-validating them as "The Authorised"-entity to deliver them and/or providing any tampering-control checkups, if & as needed

Can also
receive and respond to any "soft"-signal request or asynchronously notifying any explicit state-changes (implicit state-changes detection is naturally the Master's task, after not receiving any response and alike) related to presence / health-state / state-of-work, etc, if needed, either by re-using the primary `PUB/SUB` channel and delivering such respective responsed via the primary `PUSH/PULL` upstream one. Yet there is no problem to setup a knowingly separate, Master-offloading, secondary signalling `PUB` and/or other channels among Workers themselves plus the Master, so as to keep any kind of "soft"-signalling flow independent of the primary workloads ( the custom-defined [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) can indeed create any sort of "Parallel Universe", where Master is (or is not) a part thereof <sub>;o)</sub> )